# spock framework how to stub a list that is streamed by map function

Tags: java, java-stream, spock, stub

I have a method to use in a stream map method:

```
private static MyEntry convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry(Map<String, Object> entryToConvert) {
    return new MyEntry(String.valueOf(entryToConvert.get("mandant.path")),
              String.valueOf(entryToConvert.get("mail.to")),
              Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(entryToConvert.get("active"))));
}
```

I use this method in this method that streames over a Map and for every map entry it will call the above method:

```
private List<MyEntry> createMandantLinkCheckerEntries(Map<String, Object> mapOfEntries) {
    return Stream.of(mapOfEntries)
             .map(convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So now I want to Stub this with my Spock test. The problem here is that I do not know what **map** is calling of the **mapOfEntries**. I tried to stub **Map#keySet** and **Map#get** but that did not worked. I'm not sure what to stub to return stubbed values so the **convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry** receives valid test values.

**Edit #1**: Forgot to tell what I'm trying to stub. I want to stub the **entryToConvert** values returned by the keys *active*, *mandant.path* and *mail.to*

Comment: Steram.of(T) returns a stream with one element.
For me it is not clear why you do this. May be simplified to: 
return Arrays.asList(convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry(map));

Comment: About testing. I propose to open this private method to default package visibility and test it separately. Or you are trying to test something else and you need to stub createMandantLinkCheckerEntries() only?

Comment: To stub the entryToConvert map is not a big deal. The problem is how to pass this stubbed map into your method? Both methods are private. What are you planing to test? Is there other public method which calls your createXXX() method and passes a map (in our case it will be stubbed one) as an argument? Understand - we couldn't stub a class in general, we should stub a specific instance and use it in the testing.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote: "I want to stub the entryToConvert values returned by the keys active, mandant.path and mail.to."

Here an example how to mock a map on spock:

```
def "stub map"() {
    given:
    def map = Mock(HashMap)
    map.get("mandant.path")  >> "1"

    expect:
    map.get("mandant.path") == "1"
}
```

---

But I don't recommend it because Map is very simple class which doesn't require mocking/stubbing.

Here the same map without mocking:

```
def "normal map"() {
    given:
    def map = ["mandant.path" : "1"]

    expect:
    map.get("mandant.path") == "1"
}
```

So, in your case we need to rework a design of your business methods to have an ability to test it.